# mod_proxy: how to proxy requests begin with app* to single balencer

Tags: configuration, mod-proxy

My requirement is to proxy request  all request that starts with app to single balencer

```
ProxyPass /app balancer://ajpCluster1/app stickysession=JSESSIONID
ProxyPassReverse /app balancer://ajpCluster1/app stickysession=JSESSIONID

ProxyPass /app1 balancer://ajpCluster1/app1 stickysession=JSESSIONID
ProxyPassReverse /app1 balancer://ajpCluster1/app1 stickysession=JSESSIONID

ProxyPass /app2 balancer://ajpCluster1/app2 stickysession=JSESSIONID
ProxyPassReverse /app2 balancer://ajpCluster1/app2 stickysession=JSESSIONID
```

I want replace all above with single proxypass like below

```
ProxyPass /app* balancer://ajpCluster1/app* stickysession=JSESSIONID
ProxyPassReverse /app* balancer://ajpCluster1/app* stickysession=JSESSIONID
```